# How to plot a surface z=f(x,y) with a hole?

Tags: r, 3d, mesh, surface, rgl

I want to make a plot similar to the one at left (the goal is to illustrate an interpolation: the plot at right).

[image]

I did this plot with a constrained Delaunay tessellation (with the **delaunay** package) applied to the points `(x,y)` given on a grid with a hole and then I constructed a 3D **rgl** mesh. I'm wondering whether there exists a more straightforward method. I tried `rgl::perps3d.deldir` but it fills the hole and even if it is possible to remove this part, this way is really too slow.

Here is the grid with the hole and the `z` values:

```r
x <- y <- seq(-3, 3, by = 0.1)
Grid <- expand.grid(X = x, Y = y)
toremove <- with(Grid, X >= -0.5 & X <= 1 & Y >= -0.5 & Y <= 1)
Grid <- Grid[!toremove, ]
z <- with(Grid, dt(X, df = 1) * dt(Y, df = 1))
```

I also want to be able to add another plot to the first one (the black interpolated part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just set the values in the hole to NA, e.g.

```r
library(rgl)
x <- y <- seq(-3, 3, by = 0.1)
Grid <- expand.grid(X = x, Y = y)
toremove <- with(Grid, X >= -0.5 & X <= 1 & Y >= -0.5 & Y <= 1)
z <- with(Grid, dt(X, df = 1) * dt(Y, df = 1))
z[toremove] <- NA
persp3d(x, y, z, col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you have a situation where some x, y pairs actually cause errors in the z calculation, then it's a little trickier:  put the real function in a wrapper that returns NA for the hole.